# Unminimize window Apple script not working when upgrading from El capitan to Mojave

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applescript, mojave, script

I have an Apple script that I found somewhere that unminimizes windows. It worked on El Capitan but now it doesn't in Mojave. I assume there was a change of syntax but I know nothing about apple scripts.

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
        click (last UI element of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
    end tell
end try
```

Is there a way to get this script working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with updating it switched back to Australia language instead US english. So "minimized" is spelled "minimised" in the script. Also an updated script with error checking is below but change to `minimised` for UK or Australian English:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Dock"
        tell list 1
            try
                set minimizedWindows to every UI element whose role description is "minimized window dock item"
                if minimizedWindows is not {} then
                    click last item of minimizedWindows
                else
                    say "No minimized windows" volume 0.5 without waiting until completion
                end if
            on error errstr
                display alert errstr
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *code*, **as is**, works for me in **macOS Mojave** when run from **Script Editor**; however, I do have **Script Editor** set to have [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) for this to work properly.

If you are running that *code* from its own **AppleScript** app, or whatever you are running the *code* from, then you need to allow it *accessibility privileges* as described in the link.

Also note that the *checkbox* for **[] Minimize windows into application icon** in **System Preferences** > **Dock** must be unchecked for there to be a *window* to restore, if one is minimized.

> **To enable accessibility control for an app**
>
> 1. Launch System Preferences and click Security & Privacy.
> 2. Click the Privacy tab.
> 3. Click Accessibility.
> 4. Click the Add button (+).
> 5. Choose an app and click Open.
> 6. Select the checkbox to the left of the app.